# portlets content can't find the place on webpage Kademi platform

Tags: javascript, java, kademi

my dashboard use some portlets, and i want to edit them so can create my own style at Kademi platform.

Could you tell how i can find them and edit/create new one.
for example this portlet :

**#portlets("dashboardPrimary")**

Thanks.

Comment: Which dashboard? Which portlets? You will need to be a lot more specific, as otherwise readers won't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: HI, trying to edit dashaboard.html pages, i think there one dashboard right ?

Comment: the this dashboard, it's when user loggin go into this this pages, so  i think it's user/dashboard.html

Comment: What portlet are you trying to edit?

Comment: FYI #portlets("dashboardPrimary") is NOT a portlet, it defines a portlet section. Other apps will inject their portlets into that section. So you need to figure out which app has the portlet you want to edit, eg e-learning, blogs, calendars, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To edit a portlet you simply override the template which generates it. For example, the dashboard alerts app renders current alerts into the "beforeDashboardPrimary" portlet section with this template:

https://github.com/Kademi/kademi-dev/blob/master/src/main/webapp/templates/apps/alerts/dashboardAlerts.html

```
#foreach($msg in $alerts)
<div class="dashboard-alert alert alert-${msg.type}" >
    #if( $msg.id )    
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
      <a class="hide msg" href="$msg.href">Ack</a>
    #end
    $msg.body
</div>
#end
```

So to change the layout of dashboard alert messages you would create your own template at:
/theme/apps/alerts/dashboardAlerts.html

Answer (score 0):

the dashboardPrimary portlet get's used by several apps.
Here is a list of built in kademi apps that use it:

- **Reward Store app:** /theme/apps/rewardstore/dashboardCategories.html
- **My Files App:** /theme/apps/myfiles/filesPortlet.html
- **Blogs App:** /theme/apps/blogs/dashboardBlogs.html
- **Learning App:** /theme/apps/learner/dashboardModules.html
- **Vouchers App:**

  - **If redeemer:** /theme/apps/vouchers/redeemerPortlet.html
  - **If Supervisor:** /theme/apps/vouchers/supervisorPortlet.html

There is a good tutorial on Kademi's doc site on templating in kademi:
http://docs.kademi.co/programs/dev/d1/d11/p1.html

I hope this helps :-)

Comment: Hi, about the dashboard pages, when user loggin, where i can find the information on this ?
all those i found them before but they not helping me.

Comment: this Dashboard root exaclty at  apps/user/dashboard.html

Comment: the apps listed above inject their content into the dashboard portlet section if they are enabled. Simply override whichever of those templates you want to customise